# Add additional variables to dplyr summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that I would like to group by a variable (a, in the example below) and summarize the maximum value of a different variable (b, in the example below). In addition I want to print the value for a third (c, in the example below) variable that correspond to the maximum observation. My code work in some cases but if variable c is NA for all observations within the group then an error is returned. Is there an easy way to resolve this problem?

```
library(dplyr)
mydf<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4,4),b=c("car","banana","phone","computer","ipod","phone"),c=c(7,2,3,4,9,8))
mydf
group_by(mydf,a) %>% summarise(max(c),b[which.max(c)])

mydf<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4,4),b=c("car","banana","phone","computer","ipod","phone"),c=c(7,2,3,4,NA,NA))
mydf
group_by(mydf,a) %>% summarise(max(c),b[which.max(c)])
```

Comment: The problem is that some group have only NA elements.  What would be your expected output when  c is NA for a particular group?  Try `group_by(mydf,a) %>% slice(which.max(c))`

Comment: What do you want it to return when all observations in a group are `NA`?

Comment: I see what I am looking for is not necessarily possible; the slice function provide what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option using `dplyr` to get the rows where the `max` value of 'c' is found (grouped by 'a').

```
 library(dplyr)
 group_by(mydf,a) %>% 
            slice(which.max(c))
```

Or if need to return 'NA' for 'b' and 'c' columns grouped by 'a' where all the elements in 'b' is NA, then we can use `data.tanle`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(mydf)`), grouped by 'a', `if` `all` the 'c' elements are 'NA', we return NA by subsetting `.SD` with an index that is not present (`.SD[.N+1]`) or `else` return the Subset of Data.table where the 'max' value of 'c' is found (`.SD[which.max(c)]`).

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(mydf)[,if(all(is.na(c))) .SD[.N+1] else .SD[which.max(c)]  , by = a]
#   a        b  c
#1: 1      car  7
#2: 2    phone  3
#3: 3 computer  4
#4: 4       NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it using `data.table` as:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[order(-c), .SD[1L], keyby=a]
```

In `dplyr`, this'd translate into:

```
require(dplyr)
mydf %>% arrange(-c) %>% group_by(a) %>% slice(1L)
# slice seems to auto sort by 'a'
```